# How to avoid loading a module multiple times?

Tags: python, module

So I found a problem while "creating" modules. Let's say I create a nice module called `foo` in which I define a function named `function` that depends on `numpy`:

**foo.py:**

```
"""
This is foo a nice module
"""
import numpy as np

def function(parameter):
    return(np.zeros(parameter))
```

Then in another script I want to call my module:

```
import foo
```

So my problem is that `numpy` module is loaded inside foo so I can call it from foo (for example I can `foo.np.zeros()`)

Is there any way that I'm not aware of in which the module will still work without having all `numpy` loaded inside it (naturally `numpy` should be loaded globally so foo works but i don't want it to be accessible from `foo.np`)

So far I've tried:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     import numpy as np
```

But this breaks the module `foo` even if `numpy` is loaded.

Comment: It should not be a problem that people _can_ call numpy off of `foo`; if they know it's there and they want to, why stop them? But if you want to make sure it's not publicly accessible, you could [use a `__all__` variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), or just rename it to `import numpy as _np`, as names that start with an underscore aren't visible by default (though if you know they're there you can still use them externally)

Comment: It's not much of a problem that they use it, is just that I have a bunch on imports and I dont want the autocomplete to be full with those and not with the useful functions that my package has. The __all__ solution wont work for me because I need the dot notation so in my example function would have to be called as `foo.function` not just `function`.  So I think I'll give the underscore solution a try

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your IDE / code editor…

Comment: It might be a problem I'm using the july release of VScode on Ubuntu. I'll have to try in annother IDE but @GreenCloakGuy solution worked like a charm. Thank you both very much for your input